# static_cast doesn't work. C style cast works. How to repair static_cast?

Tags: c++, random, static-cast

It works fine:

```
srand(time(NULL));
cout<<(double)rand()/RAND_MAX<<endl;
```

It doesn't work:

```
srand(time(NULL));
cout<<static_cast<double>(rand()/RAND_MAX)<<endl;
```

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: Those aren't even kinda equivalent.  Your `static_cast<>()` example is casting the entire division expression while the C version is only casting `rand()`'s output.

Comment: Precedence. Only `rand()` is casted in the first snippet.

Comment: Ah  ok, thanks! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(double)rand()/RAND_MAX
```

Here you cast only `rand()` number. So in your code it should be like that too:

```
static_cast<double>(rand())/RAND_MAX
```

In your example you were dividing two `int`s then casting it into `double`.